# Thinkpad T460 - how do I disable the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, xinput, trackpoint

I recently got a Thinkpad T460 and am running Ubuntu 20.04 on it. I don't use a DE, just plain old i3.

I'm like to keep my hands on the keyboard. That's why I like the trackpoint. However, I keep accidentally touching the touchpad, resulting in unwanted mouse movements and even clicks (even though I barely touch it!)

I'm exploring multiple options to improve the situation. This question is about disabling the touchpad completely. According to `xinput list`, there is only one device (see below):

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And if I run `xinput disable 11`, both trackpoint and touchpad are disabled.

How can I disable ONLY the touchpad?

Comment: maybe in system settings (BIOS)

Comment: That's odd. I have owned two T-series thinkpads, and am currently typing on one of them, and on both I had a separate entry for the touchpad and track point: `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` and `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` on my T460p. We seem to basically have the exact same machine, and I can disable/enable the touchpad and trackpoint separately on my Arch (just tested now).  Is there any way you may have parsed out the relevant entry in the output you show us?

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, that was too obvious. Feel free to write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @terdon I agree it's odd. I didn't change the output. Also notice how disabling one disables both.

Comment: yeah, that's the really weird thing. Assuming we do have the same hardware (mine's a T460p bought almost 5 years ago now), it must come down to whatever software is recognizing it. If the BIOS option isn't a solution, you could try a different distro in case that makes a difference. I would be really curious to know if Arch, for example, gives you the same output.

Comment: @Sören just delete your question ... changing system setup is not Unix/Linux solution so the answer would be off topic

Comment: @terdon I just found out, why I only have one entry. I have "options psmouse proto=imps" in /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf. Without it, I have separate entries for touchpad and trackpoint. But also very erratic behavior when I use the trackpoint. I guess that's what you get when you buy used hardware.

Comment: Huh. I haven't used the trackpoint much (I always have a mouse connected) so I can't confirm that it's erratic for me too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my hardware has a slight defect.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with Fedora 37 activating a touchpad I don't want to use on my T470p.

Solution was very simple: Settings (gear icon)-->Mouse and Touchpad-->Touchpad section-->Touchpad toggle-->off.